# Who provides the C standard library gcc or glibc?

Tags: c, c-standard-library

I am reading C Primer Plus. On page 31, the author says:

> The `stdio.h` file is supplied as part of all C compiler packages.

But the author didn't specify from where the actual library code comes from.

I am on a Linux system and I have confusion between `gcc` or `glibc`.

So which one provides the actual code?

Comment: GCC have some of the compiler-specific parts of the standard library, while glibc have the the rest of the standard library (and a lot of other functionality, the POSIX system interface for example).

Comment: So, it's `glibc` right?

Comment: You can always check which package supplies `/usr/include/stdio.h`. Most package systems have functionality to check for that.

Comment: And besides, does it really matter? You can't have a modern (since 15-20 years or so) Linux system without glibc, and GCC is the standard compiler which you need to develop in C. Why does it matter which package provides which part of the standard library?

Comment: Just for the information purpose. When I first started learning C years ago on Windows, I didn't have any idea what going on behind the scenes. Now, I am looking to expand my horizons.

Comment: In case of Windows/Mingw, it is Microsoft C runtime library. Which has not been updated for 30 years or so.

Comment: @Lundin that's not correct. MS has updated its C runtime library quite a number of times. The most notable one is the one with C99 support https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013/ [MS runtime library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#MSVCRT.DLL,_MSVCP*.DLL_and_CRTDLL.DLL), [*Newer versions of Visual Studio use newer runtimes, but these are not always supplied with the operating system or freely downloadable, which makes their use with Open Source software difficult*](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/C99)

Comment: @phuclv And yet the library remains non-compliant...

Answer (score 0):

The implementation depends on your system. For Linux, it is [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library).

You can see other implementations 
 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library